# How to assign values to a new column based on the oldest date?

Tags: r

Is there a way to assign a value "CH" to a new column res$A if the oldest date is found is columns A_returne, B_date, C_returned_date and assign a value "CL" if the oldest date is found in columns A_ordered, B_received.

```
  record_id  inst instance  A_returne     B_date C_returned_date D_returned_date  A_ordered B_received
1         1             NA            2018-10-29      2018-11-10      2021-05-21                      
2         2             NA 2019-11-07                                                                 
3         3             NA 2019-11-08                                                                 
4         4             NA 2019-11-07                                                                 
5         5             NA            2018-11-27      2018-12-12                                      
6         5 rectr        1                                                       2021-01-14 2021-02-17
```

I tried:

```
library(dplyr)
res1 <- res %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.character), \(x) na_if(x, ""))) %>%
  group_by(record_id) %>%
  fill(A_returne, C_returned_date, D_returned_date, .direction="downup", .direction="downup") %>%
  filter(inst == "rectr") %>%
  mutate(oldest_date=pmin(A_returne, C_returned_date, D_returned_date, na.rm=TRUE))
```

### data

```
res <- structure(list(record_id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L), inst = c("", 
"", "", "", "", "rectr"), instance = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L
), A_returne = c("", "2019-11-07", "2019-11-08", "2019-11-07", 
"", ""), B_date = c("2018-10-29", "", "", "", "2018-11-27", ""
), C_returned_date = c("2018-11-10", "", "", "", "2018-12-12", 
""), D_returned_date = c("2021-05-21", "", "", "", "", ""), A_ordered = c("", 
"", "", "", "", "2021-01-14"), B_received = c("", "", "", "", 
"", "2021-02-17")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a dplyr solution:

```
res %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), \(x) {
    x[x==""] <- NA 
    x
  })) %>% 
  mutate(across(A_returne:B_received, as.Date)) %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(ifelse(min(c(A_returne, B_date, C_returned_date, D_returned_date), na.rm = T) < 
                min(c(A_ordered, B_received), na.rm = T),
                "CH" ,
                "CL"
  )
  )

# A tibble: 6 × 10
# Rowwise: 
  record_id inst  instance A_returne  B_date     C_returned_date D_returned_date A_ordered  B_received `ifelse(...)`
      <int> <chr>    <int> <date>     <date>     <date>          <date>          <date>     <date>     <chr>        
1         1 NA          NA NA         2018-10-29 2018-11-10      2021-05-21      NA         NA         CH           
2         2 NA          NA 2019-11-07 NA         NA              NA              NA         NA         CH           
3         3 NA          NA 2019-11-08 NA         NA              NA              NA         NA         CH           
4         4 NA          NA 2019-11-07 NA         NA              NA              NA         NA         CH           
5         5 NA          NA NA         2018-11-27 2018-12-12      NA              NA         NA         CH           
6         5 rectr        1 NA         NA         NA              NA              2021-01-14 2021-02-17 CL
```

I was not sure wether to use `D_returned_date` or not as it was not mentioned in your question. I added it to computation.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in base R by first finding the names of the columns with the `max` date values (`maxcols`), then use `ifelse`:

```
# Define and convert date columns from character to actual dates
dts <- c("A_returne", "B_date", "C_returned_date", "D_returned_date", "A_ordered", "B_received")
res[dts] <- lapply(res[dts], as.Date)

maxcols <- names(res[dts])[apply(res[dts], 1, \(x) which(x == max(x, na.rm = TRUE)))]

res$A <- ifelse(maxcols %in% c("A_returne", "B_date", "C_returned_date"), "CH", "CL")
```

Output:

```
#  record_id  inst instance  A_returne     B_date C_returned_date D_returned_date  A_ordered B_received  A
# 1         1             NA       <NA> 2018-10-29      2018-11-10      2021-05-21       <NA>       <NA> CL
# 2         2             NA 2019-11-07       <NA>            <NA>            <NA>       <NA>       <NA> CH
# 3         3             NA 2019-11-08       <NA>            <NA>            <NA>       <NA>       <NA> CH
# 4         4             NA 2019-11-07       <NA>            <NA>            <NA>       <NA>       <NA> CH
# 5         5             NA       <NA> 2018-11-27      2018-12-12            <NA>       <NA>       <NA> CH
# 6         5 rectr        1       <NA>       <NA>            <NA>            <NA> 2021-01-14 2021-02-17 CL
```

Comment: I am trying dplyr::if_else() which partially works but am not sure how to handle NA

Answer (score 0):

If we remove the hyphens in the ISO dates, we could `type.convert` them and `apply` row-wise `which.max`.

```
res[res == ""] <- NA
c('CL', 'CH')[grepl('[AC]_r|B_d', names(res[4:9])[apply(type.convert(gsub('\\D', '', as.matrix(res[4:9])), as.is=TRUE), 1, which.max)]) + 1L]

# [1] "CL" "CH" "CH" "CH" "CH" "CL"
```

---

*Data:*

```
res <- structure(list(record_id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L), inst = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "rectr"), instance = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L
), A_returne = c(NA, "2019-11-07", "2019-11-08", "2019-11-07", 
NA, NA), B_date = c("2018-10-29", NA, NA, NA, "2018-11-27", NA
), C_returned_date = c("2018-11-10", NA, NA, NA, "2018-12-12", 
NA), D_returned_date = c("2021-05-21", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), A_ordered = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "2021-01-14"), B_received = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "2021-02-17")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```